# Fork in C and then pass data to Python3 program with a pipe

Tags: python-3.x, fdopen

I fork in c, call a python program from child process and pass a string from parent. Now i will print this string on my python program.
I have this Code:

```
void
forking ()
{
int thepipe[2];
char someString[] = "Hello, world!\n";
char readbuffer[80];

if (pipe (thepipe) < 0)
    {
    perror ("pipe error");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
pid_t pid = fork ();
if (pid < 0)
    {
    perror ("Fork failed");
    }
if (pid == 0)
    {
    close (thepipe[1]);
    execl(PYTHONPROGRAM, PYTHONPROGRAM);
    exit (0);
    }
else
    {
    close (thepipe[0]);
    write (thepipe[1], someString, (strlen (someString) + 1));
    wait (NULL);
    }
}
```

How can i read the pipe from the python program?
I have to use os.fdopen. The code below did not work.

```
import os,sys
r, w = os.pipe()
os.close(w)
r = os.fdopen(r)
str = r.read()
print("text =", str)
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: You can just copy the pipe[0] file descriptor to fd 0 in the child before the exec, and then read standard input in your python program. Something like: `close(thepipe[1]); dup2(thepipe[0], 0); close(thepipe[0]); execl(PYTHONPROGRAM, PYTHONPROGRAM);`.

Comment: What do you mean with fd 0?

Comment: Sorry, I meant file descriptor 0. After the `dup2(thepipe[0], 0)`, `read`s from file descriptor 0 will read from the pipe. After the `execl`, Python will get its standard input from file descriptor 0. So effectively, the Python program gets its standard input from the pipe.

Comment: Your current Python program is creating another pipe which has nothing to do with the pipe created by the parent process.

Comment: Oh ok, so i can't use fdopen then?

Comment: Ok, so if i do: for line in sys.stdin:  print("line") in the python file it works.

Comment: You can use `fdopen` in your Python program if you know which file descriptor number corresponds to the "read" end of the pipe created before the exec, but you would probably have to pass that information via a command-line parameter (or some other means).